# Word that describes the phenomenon where the order of two words cannot be reversed

Tags: single-word-requests

Essentially, the word I'm looking for describes how the order of two words only sounds correct one way.

Eg. Salt and Pepper not Pepper and Salt, or Ladies and Gentlemen not Gentlemen and Ladies.

I know that this must happen because we're so used to hearing it a certain way, but I know that there's a word that describes it. I remember learning about it in my Grade 10 English class, but it's buried in my brain next to the pile of Shakespeare's plays!

Comment: _Pepper and salt_ doesn't sound wrong to me, and, as [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pepper+and+salt&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, was especially common in the early 19th century. It's traditionally considered polite to mention ladies first.